# The script stops working when the card is switched

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem. I have a script created for converting text links and a slider. The problem with this script the only problem is that when someone leaves the tab and comes back to the page it all jars and doesn't match. The images are different than the caption and link. I need it to always work together how can I fix this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
let slideWidth = slides[0].offsetWidth;
let centerOffset = (carousel.offsetWidth - slideWidth) / 2;
let currentCenterIndex = 2;
let animationId;

function updateSlideWidth() {
    slideWidth = slides[0].offsetWidth;
    centerOffset = (carousel.offsetWidth - slideWidth) / 2;
}

function goToSlide(index) {
    const slideOffset = centerOffset - slideWidth * index;
    carousel.style.transform = `translateX(${slideOffset}px)`;
    currentCenterIndex = index;
    slides.forEach((slide, i) => {
        if (i === currentCenterIndex) {
            slide.classList.add('color-slide');
        } else {
            slide.classList.remove('color-slide');
        }
    });
}

function nextSlide() {
    if (currentCenterIndex < slides.length - 1) {
        goToSlide(currentCenterIndex + 1);
    } else {
        currentCenterIndex = 0;
        goToSlide(currentCenterIndex);
    }
}

function animateCarousel(timestamp) {
    if (!animationId) {
        animationId = timestamp;
    }
    const delta = timestamp - animationId;

    if (delta >= 7600) {
        nextSlide();
        animationId = null;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animateCarousel);
}

function startCarousel() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animateCarousel);
}

function stopCarousel() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(animationId);
}

function handleVisibilityChange() {
    if (document.hidden) {
        stopCarousel();
    } else {
        startCarousel();
    }
}

function handleResize() {
    updateSlideWidth();
    goToSlide(currentCenterIndex);
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange);
updateSlideWidth();
goToSlide(currentCenterIndex);
startCarousel();
window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

class TxtType {
    constructor(el, toRotate, period) {
        this.toRotate = toRotate;
        this.el = el;
        this.loopNum = 0;
        this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 1000;
        this.txt = '';
        this.totalTime = 9000;
        this.timePerChar = this.totalTime / (this.toRotate.join('').length * 2);
        this.isDeleting = false;
        this.animationComplete = false;
        this.tick();
    }

    tick() {
        var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
        var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];
        if (this.isDeleting) {
            this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
        } else {
            this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
        }
        this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + this.txt + '</span>';
        var that = this;
        var delta = this.isDeleting ? this.timePerChar / 2 : this.timePerChar;
        if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
            delta = this.period - this.timePerChar * fullTxt.length;
            this.isDeleting = true;
        } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
            this.isDeleting = false;
            this.loopNum++;
            delta = 500;
        }
        if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
            delta = this.period - this.timePerChar * fullTxt.length;
            this.isDeleting = true;
            this.animationComplete = true;
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            that.tick();
        }, delta);
    }
}

function startTypingAnimation() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
        var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
        if (toRotate) {
            new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
        }
    }
}

startTypingAnimation();
});

const hrefList = [
  'https://img.pakamera.net/i1/1/954/obrazy-i-plakaty-12320957_8726585954.jpg', 
  'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ81TeqUX-phCYKFpSQXOLwv2qFIzBjQ8MWJQ&usqp=CAU', 
  'https://www.youtube.com/',
  'https://samequizy.pl/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/filing_images_fdc4a96bd066.jpg', 
  'https://www.national-geographic.pl/media/cache/big/uploads/media/default/0014/57/naukowcy-chca-wyslac-kosmitom-obrazek-z-nagimi-ludzmi-co-jeszcze-znajdzie-sie-w-wiadomosci.jpeg', 
  'https://img.freepik.com/premium-zdjecie/pies-animowany-obrazek-generatywna-sztuczna-inteligencja_786688-641.jpg', 
  'https://sdpl.b-cdn.net/8415-large_default/obrazek-obrazki-ob-04-09.jpg/', 
  'https://naklejki.sklep.pl/images/console/image/resize/nowatermark/1/type/productGfx/image/2604.jpg',
  'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSPbHy7btvXSXtbzrbwaXB6MmkbeNsysGHrfQ&usqp=CAU',
  'https://a.allegroimg.com/original/110591/24e5c72d41f3acd8adea6a2c6380/Obrazek-A3-plakat-grafika-dla-dzieci'
];

function updateHref() {
  const spanElement = document.querySelector('.thanks_for_support .text');
  const currentHref = spanElement.parentNode.getAttribute('href');
  const currentIndex = hrefList.indexOf(currentHref);
  const nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % hrefList.length;
  const newHref = hrefList[nextIndex];
  spanElement.parentNode.setAttribute('href', newHref);
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  updateHref();
  const intervalTime = 7700; 
  const interval = setInterval(updateHref, intervalTime);
});
```

```css
.carousel-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }

.carousel {
    display: flex;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out !important; 
}

.slide img {
    width: 384px;
    height: 305px;
    filter: grayscale(1);
    transition: scale 1.4s;
    scale: .7;
}

.color-slide img {
    filter: grayscale(0);
    scale: .9;
    opacity: 1;
}

.thanks_for_support {
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: normal;    
}

.thanks_for_support span {
    color: #60B558;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: normal;
}

.thanks_for_support h4 a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.thanks_for_support h4 a span:hover {
    color: #50A447;
}

.typewrite > .wrap {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.typewrite > .wrap::after {
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    width: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -2%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    animation: closeBar 1.6s infinite .7s ease-out;
}

@keyframes closeBar {
    0% {
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }
    50%{
        height: 0%;
        top: 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="thanks_for_support">
 <h4 style="min-height: 68px;">THANKS: <br/><a href=""><span class="text typewrite" data-period="7000" data-type="[&quot;TEST&quot;, &quot;AAAAA&quot;, &quot;BBB&quot;, &quot;ZZZZZ&quot;, &quot;EEEE&quot; ,&quot;WWWW&quot; ,&quot;XXXX&quot; ,&quot;YYYYYz&quot;,&quot;SSSSS&quot;,&quot;QQQQQ&quot;]"></span></a></h4>
</div>
<div class="carousel-container">
<div class="carousel" data-period="7600">
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="https://img.pakamera.net/i1/1/954/obrazy-i-plakaty-12320957_8726585954.jpg">
      <img src="https://img.pakamera.net/i1/1/954/obrazy-i-plakaty-12320957_8726585954.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ81TeqUX-phCYKFpSQXOLwv2qFIzBjQ8MWJQ&usqp=CAU">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ81TeqUX-phCYKFpSQXOLwv2qFIzBjQ8MWJQ&usqp=CAU" >
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide color-slide">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
      <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="https://samequizy.pl/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/filing_images_fdc4a96bd066.jpg">
      <img src="https://samequizy.pl/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/filing_images_fdc4a96bd066.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="https://www.national-geographic.pl/media/cache/big/uploads/media/default/0014/57/naukowcy-chca-wyslac-kosmitom-obrazek-z-nagimi-ludzmi-co-jeszcze-znajdzie-sie-w-wiadomosci.jpeg">
      <img src="https://www.national-geographic.pl/media/cache/big/uploads/media/default/0014/57/naukowcy-chca-wyslac-kosmitom-obrazek-z-nagimi-ludzmi-co-jeszcze-znajdzie-sie-w-wiadomosci.jpeg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="https://img.freepik.com/premium-zdjecie/pies-animowany-obrazek-generatywna-sztuczna-inteligencja_786688-641.jpg">
      <img src="https://img.freepik.com/premium-zdjecie/pies-animowany-obrazek-generatywna-sztuczna-inteligencja_786688-641.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="https://sdpl.b-cdn.net/8415-large_default/obrazek-obrazki-ob-04-09.jpg">
      <img src="https://sdpl.b-cdn.net/8415-large_default/obrazek-obrazki-ob-04-09.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="https://naklejki.sklep.pl/images/console/image/resize/nowatermark/1/type/productGfx/image/2604.jpg">
      <img src="https://naklejki.sklep.pl/images/console/image/resize/nowatermark/1/type/productGfx/image/2604.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSPbHy7btvXSXtbzrbwaXB6MmkbeNsysGHrfQ&usqp=CAU">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSPbHy7btvXSXtbzrbwaXB6MmkbeNsysGHrfQ&usqp=CAU">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="https://a.allegroimg.com/original/110591/24e5c72d41f3acd8adea6a2c6380/Obrazek-A3-plakat-grafika-dla-dzieci">
      <img src="https://a.allegroimg.com/original/110591/24e5c72d41f3acd8adea6a2c6380/Obrazek-A3-plakat-grafika-dla-dzieci">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please simplify your example to a [mcve]

Comment: I suggest that in `animateCarousel` function, you check if `pause` global variable is true or false, then listen to the window focus window unfocus event and then update the `pause` global variable. this way, same would apply to the text typing

Comment: like the `visibilitychange` handler you need to load the event and not reference the `document.hidden` value